# How do I add the kernel PPA?

Tags: kernel, updates, package-management, ppa

I can get Ubuntu mainline kernels from [this kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) - is there a way to add it to my repository list the same as regular Launchpad PPAs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Warning**: This answer is outdated. As of writing this warning (6.10.2013) the kernel-ppa used here is no longer updated. Please disregard this answer.

*Small note:* Installing anything but the official standard kernel for your system is not recommended. It might be unstable or buggy. Now to the topic:

This adds the daily build of ubuntu kernel (not mainline):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install PACKAGENAME
```

You can do the same with Software Center or Synaptic using the menu item "Repositories". From there you'll need to click through some self explanatory stuff.

You might be interested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47086/whats-the-best-way-to-update-the-linux-kernel-if-i-have-no-internet-connection/47088#47088).

Comment: This is the correct answer .

Comment: Are mainline without Ubuntu's configuration? And what kernel release are the daily builds based on?

Comment: As you might know, ubuntu is based on Debian. With mainline I meant the kernel released for Debian. A small delay aside the images from kernel-ppa are based on the latest stable kernel from www.kernel.org. Disregard - it's acutally the same ppa

Comment: Adding the PPA itself does not upgrade me to the latest kernel, what do I do?

Comment: You install the kernel's package in Synaptic?

Comment: I don't think kernel ppa (on launchpad) is being updated anymore...

Comment: There are no kernels for Precise available in this ppa.

Comment: The PPA linked in the question currently (2020) is updated often. But your code does not work any more. any way to add it manually?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot . you can install like this .

> Installing Mainline Kernels
>
> To use the mainline kernel as-is you
>   only only need to download and install
>   the *image*.deb package that
>   corresponds to your architecture,
>   however if you need to build any
>   external modules you also need the
>   correct *header*.deb and *source*.deb
>   packages.
>
> To install, download the common
>   headers, architecture specific
>   headers, and the architecture specific
>   image. For example for 2.6.27.15 we
>   have the following files, for i386 you
>   would need those marked with B and C,
>   amd64 take those marked A & C:
>
> ```
> A       linux-headers-2.6.27-02062715-generic_2.6.27-02062715_amd64.deb
> B       linux-headers-2.6.27-02062715-generic_2.6.27-02062715_i386.deb
> C       linux-headers-2.6.27-02062715_2.6.27-02062715_all.deb
> A       linux-image-2.6.27-02062715-generic_2.6.27-02062715_amd64.deb
> B       linux-image-2.6.27-02062715-generic_2.6.27-02062715_i386.deb
> ```
>
> Once you have those downloaded they
>   will need to be installed using dpkg:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
> ```

[Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

Comment: I already know how to manually download and install - hoped to add a repo for it to be done automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since the kernel ppa is not really maintained anymore, here's a semi-automatic script:

https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader

https://askubuntu.com/a/177586/5538

Answer (score 0):

These days you can add the repo in sources.list, but you will get an error on install:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-firmware but it is not installable
                       Depends: intel-microcode but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: amd64-microcode but it is not installable
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70992979/4240654