# overheating laptop even on low cpu usage

Tags: ati, fglrx, overheating

I am using ubuntu 12.10 latest release ,but the problem is not really limited to this version.
The laptop is equipped with Ati 5400 series Raedon graphics.
I tried to install the fglrx driver, but it broke unity no panel and launcher.
what should i do and what is the reason of this?

Please comment for any more data that u need.

Sony Vaio E series,
i5 core processor,
ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.
default gpu drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the open source driver (radeon) [see some answers in this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161233/set-ati-amd-gpu-fan-speed-with-mesa-driver/199017#199017)

If you want to install and use the fglrx driver in Ubuntu 12.10, the try this:

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Or (if you want to try the updates)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

Reboot your system.

Comment: i did write that this breaks unity.