# HP Probook 4510s Overheating Issue

Tags: radeon, hp, overheating, sensors, lm-sensors

I have an HP Probook 4510s running Ubuntu 12.10 with open source Radeon drivers also I keep my computer clean and dust free. The following output of the sensors command is worrying me.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +77.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
temp2:        +40.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp3:        +45.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
temp4:        +47.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp5:        +26.8°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
temp6:        +55.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

As you can see temp1 says 77 degrees (this can go up to 81 degrees and after booting in the morning when the laptop is completely cold it says 50 degrees). Is there a way to know which component this is? I wonder if this is just a display bug or a real overheating issue since I am not really experiencing any issues with the laptop. Also does anyone know of an alternative way of checking the temperatures (running latest BIOS but I see no options to view temperatures)?

EDIT: After some research it seems that temp1 is the temperature of my GPU and apparently temperature from 70 to 80 degrees is acceptable (but still a bit hot). I have also tried changing the power profile to dynamic which does drop the temperature to about 70 degrees but i found the occasional flicker annoying so i opted to set the power profile to auto instead (high when plugged into power, medium on battery). This results in around 78-80 degrees when plugged in and about 70-72 degrees when on battery. After that i also enabled fan always on an AC power in BIOS which dropped my plugged in GPU temperature to 77-79. Still not too completely happy with this but its best I have so far (any further ideas are welcome).

Link to change power profiles: [Set ATI/AMD GPU Fan speed with MESA Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161233/set-ati-amd-gpu-fan-speed-with-mesa-driver)

EDIT 2: In the end the only solution was to revert to 12.04.1 (not 12.04.2) so I could use the closed source AMD radeon drivers. With regular desktop usage I now get around 65-68 degrees temperature as well as much better performance. Sad to say but the open source Radeon drivers are not nearly as good as the closed source ones.