# Should I update my kernel and if so how?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

Hi I read some where that the current build of the Linux kernel is 3.5 but I am running 3.2 are there any benefits from updating and what are the risks.

Could someone also post the code to update please.

Thanks....

Comment: Use  find -name met* commands in terminal ( ctr + t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep your computer updated, that would take care of everything. I would not recommend manually updating the kernel yourself (i.e., without Update Manager or some other package management utility).

Answer (score 1):

I won't say nothing about 'should you' but yes, you can.

Here's what I found while reading online.

https://askubuntu.com/a/142236/54298

It's for kernel version 3.4, but the answer can be extended to other versions.