# How to uninstall linux kernel 3.4?

Tags: 12.04, kernel

I've installed linux kernel v3.4 in Ubuntu 12.04 containing kernel v3.2 using the answer here - [Can I install Linux kernel in Ubuntu appart of the default one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142192/can-i-install-linux-kernel-3-4-in-ubuntu-and-kubuntu-12-04)

But v3.4 is showing strange bugs like inability to move mouse (laptop touchpad), inability to connect to wifi, etc.

Could you please tell me how to uninstall v3.4 so that the default version in Linux grub becomes v3.2 as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you used the first option in the answer. To uninstall the 3.4 kernel and keep using the 3.2 kernel:

You will have to boot into the 3.2 kernel first, so you are not removing the kernel you are currently using. To do this, you will have to select the appropriate kernel on boot from the Grub menu. If you do not normally see the Grub menu, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot, and it will appear. Using the arrow keys, scroll to "Advanced options for Ubuntu [version number]" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then scroll down to the latest version of the 3.2 kernel, which is 3.2.0-40 if you have that latest version installed. Make sure not to pick Recovery Mode.

Once you have booted, open up a terminal and remove all versions of the 3.4 kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.4.0-* linux-headers-3.4.0-*
```

This will not require that you install any additional software such as Synaptic, it will simply remove the kernel. After rebooting, the kernel will be uninstalled.

Comment: I have 13.10 and I had to remove the `linux-headers` part.

Answer (score 1):

**If you used the first option** from the [answer you indicated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142192/can-i-install-linux-kernel-3-4-in-ubuntu-and-kubuntu-12-04), then use synaptic package manager.

First you need to boot from the Original Kernel. If the grub menu does not appear during boot, then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> key until reveals. From there choose **Previous Linux Versions** menu (or "advanced options for Ubuntu" if you have a newer version than 12.04) and boot from the Original Ubuntu Kernel.

Then install synaptic package manager. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and issue the following command

```
sudo apt-get install -y synaptic
```

Find and open synaptic (from Dash just write: synaptic) and search for `linux-image-3.4.0` and `linux-headers-3.4.0`. Right click and mark for removal.

[image]

Hit the apply button to remove the kernel and its headers also.