# Unable to boot after installing new kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

recently I installed the latest kernel 4.1.0-rc3 in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit.When I did reboot after make install, it is getting stuck after the grub listing the following error mentioning that it has been calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain for 4-5 times-

```
*   cfg80211:Exceeded CRDA call max. attempts. Not calling CRDA
    [234.021955] random: non-blocking pool is initialized
    Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
   - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
     - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/sda1 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a lost of built-in commands.

(initramfs)*
```

I checked for the solution in the following thread and made all the three attempts mentioned in one of the answers, but it still didn't help in correcting the error.

[Gave up waiting for root device on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To boot: select advanced options from the initial grub menu, then, choose an older kernel and then try to figure out where you went wrong with your kernel build.

Did you build a new initrd? What about grub, is it updated.

Comment: Yes Grub is updated..I can see the initrd getting created for the respective kernel using ** ls -l /boot/initrd **.. It's the same issue as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/247541/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-on-ubuntu

Comment: But the difference is that I'm not  able to get it going right even after doing all the 3 attempts mentioned in the above thread

Answer (score 0):

I faced the EXACT same problem when i tried to install a new kernel in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The reason was that you cannot install a generic linux kernel from the tree directly that way. You need an ubuntu version of whatever version you want to install.

Look at this post for reasons:

[Can I install Linux kernel in Ubuntu appart of the default one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142192/can-i-install-linux-kernel-in-ubuntu-appart-of-the-default-one)

So i followed the steps in this link to intall v4.3 in my ubuntu and it works absolutely fine:

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/05/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-0-3-in-linux.html

I'm a newbie in this field so this is what i resorted to after almost a week of struggle. If you find a way however, to install a generic kernel then please go ahead and let me know!

Good luck!

Thanks,
Sid.

Comment: I don't agree with what you said regarding installation of the generic Kernel in Ubuntu...I have installed the Generic kernel 4.0.2-040002-generic in Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit using the generic ways of make,make menuconfig , make modules,make modules_install and make install..and The new kernel booted perfectly fine...But the same steps and the processes are not going well with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit...