# Linux Kernel PPA not found

Tags: package-management, kernel, ppa

From [This](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Misc/linux-misc-1.html) article, I want to download new version of the Linux kernel so the first commands to execute is `add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa` but when I use it says that it cannod add *PPA* and that the user named `'~kernel-ppa'` has no *PPA* named `'ubuntu/ppa'`.

Why is that?

```
vm@vm:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~kernel-ppa/ubuntu/ppa'.
The user named '~kernel-ppa' has no PPA named 'ubuntu/ppa'
Please choose from the following available PPAs:
```

Comment: **NOTE:** The kernel in Ubuntu distributions has optimizations, additions and customization related to Ubuntu special "tweaks". If you replace the kernel with something from another "place" - you will most likely lose some functionality, unless you have the knowledge to re-do those. *So: "updating" the kernel ON YOUR OWN is not easy to do right.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add the kernel PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47397/how-do-i-add-the-kernel-ppa) Please read the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Use at your own risk: https://github.com/bkw777/mainline